# Where should I post questions that are relevant to desktop applications as well as web applications?

Tags: support, questions, scope, site-crossover

On https://webapps.stackexchange.com/, I once asked [whether it was possible](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30473/opening-files-from-the-desktop-using-web-applications) to open a file from the desktop using a context menu, and load it in a web browser using a web application such as pixlr. I thought it was an interesting question, but the question was closed as off-topic. It appears that questions of this nature are not allowed on either superuser.com or webapps.stackexchange.com.

Questions about "desktop software" are [considered to be off-topic on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30473/opening-files-from-the-desktop-using-web-applications), while questions about "websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress" are [considered off-topic on http://superuser.com.](https://superuser.com/faq) In that case, where should I post questions about applications that don't fit neatly into either of these categories? I'm not sure whether my question was a "web application question", a "desktop application question", or somewhere between the two.

It's not always easy to choose the right Stack Exchange site for a given question, given the intricacy of the inclusion/exclusion rules that are applied to each site. Is it possible for an application to be both a "web application" and a "desktop application" at the same time, or is there no possibility for overlap at all? If I ask how to "open a file with a web application using a context menu on the desktop", then I'm not sure if it's even possible to put it into either category.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I moved your comment into the question. That's probably a better place for it. :)

Comment: Your actual question, sounds possible, it would require a client installed to the Desktop that would help the process along by transferring the file to web app in some way using the web app's API.  I doubt that there is a generic method though, so right now the question would be specific to a single web app or site.

Answer (score 1):

This depends largely on the end application you're using.

If that means your main interaction is with the desktop side, then it would fit Super User.

If it was coming in as a user of a web app, and say wanting to save something, then it would fit Nothing 2 Install.

Dropbox is one such category of questions that have both elements, but on reading the questions you'll quickly find out if they're talking about the installed-on-your-computer app or from accessing the web app side of things. You can mostly split things across these lines. Those you can't, need examples.

Unfortunately for your question, this would most likely have killed it:

> Is there any software that makes it possible to do this?

Where being vague does not work to your question staying around long unless you specify what app (desktop or web) you're actually using.

Something as open handed as that example can fall into either "not constructive" or "off topic" depending on how the rest of the question is worded. Flip a coin if "it depends".

Comment: Do you mean that Stack Exchange users aren't allowed to ask about the existence of software with specific features? Are such questions generally considered unconstructive and unhelpful, or is there a place for them somewhere?

Comment: Depends. What specific product tag would it use?

Comment: I don't really know what a "product tag" is. Do you mean "price tag"?

Comment: In any case, asking how to implement a program with a specific features (on Stack Overflow) would be better than asking for software recommendations.

Comment: @AndersonGreen, questions asking about the existence of software often have the problems described in the [lets go shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) post.

Comment: A product tag is the name of the app you're using. Without that you're asking to set up a community wiki geared post, trying to capture the process and methods for all apps imaginable. @and

Comment: I found many questions on webapps.stackoverflow.com that could be closed as "software recommendation questions". http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=Is+there+any+software. Some of them actually appear to be useful, and I hope they won't be closed en masse.