# How can I find on which sites my question will be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-recommendation, off-topic

I'm going to ask a question about a web application, in detail how to arrange the objects on the page so the application is well usable on most devices and appears nice and practical to end users.

I went straight to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), but I discovered you cannot post questions about the development of a web application. They suggests to use [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for this topic, but they will close and downvote my question is a femtosecond claiming it is opinion-based.

I was looking for a "user-experience" site but I found nothing relevant.
There are similar questions here (for example [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168297/on-which-site-are-lilypond-questions-on-topic) one or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161424/where-should-i-post-questions-that-are-relevant-to-desktop-applications-as-well) other) about where to post.

So I'm indeed asking an advice for my specific case, but in general I wonder if there is a way to find out which site would accept a question. Like the engine that shows similar questions while you're typing, is there something that searches among *all* the SE sites in order to find out questions with similar phrasing, or better looks directly inside the on/off-topic page?

Comment: There is user experience stack exchange: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @goulashsoup ulp! I missed it! Thanks!

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog yes, but I think it would be better a search engine instead of everyone asks for his own specific case

Comment: @Mark Click on the text bubble button at the top right site of the page > "Find a stack exchange community"